# How to Parse Json Data and display it in a view in MVC?

Tags: json, view, telerik, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use Telerik's KendoUI Grid to display some data in my view.Seems like Kendo Grid only accepts Json Input. so i am trying to return JSON data in my View. Here is my code :
My Controller :

```html
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /User/
        public JsonResult DisplayUserDetails()
        {
            List<UserModel> userList = new List<UserModel>();
            userList.Add(new UserModel
            {
                FirstName="Pawan",
                LastName="Kapoor",
                Address="Mohali",
                Email="test@test.com",
                Gender = "Male",               
                Salary=25000
            }

                );

            userList.Add(new UserModel
            {
                FirstName = "Ayan",
                LastName = "Banerjee",
                Address = "Bangalore",
                Email = "test1@test.com",
                Gender="Male",
                Salary = 30000
            }

                );
            userList.Add(new UserModel
            {
                FirstName = "Palak",
                LastName = "Thakur",
                Address = "Bangalore",
                Email = "test2@test.com",
                Gender = "Female",                
                Salary = 22000
            }

                );
            //var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //var json=jsonSerializer.Serialize(userList);
            ViewBag.Response = Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return ViewBag.Response;
        }
```

```
My Model
```

```html
 public class UserModel
    {      
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="First Name is Required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Range(100,1000000)]
        public decimal Salary {get;set; }

    }
```

and My View :

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            FirstName
        </th>
        <th>
            LastName
        </th>
        <th>
            Address
        </th>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Gender
        </th>
        <th>
            Salary
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @{
        var json = ViewBag.Response;
    }
    @foreach (var item in json)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.FirstName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.LastName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Address
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Email
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Gender
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Salary
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

and i am getting the following output in my browser :

> [{\"FirstName\":\"Pawan\",\"LastName\":\"Kapoor\",\"Address\":\"Mohali\",\"Email\":\"test@test.com\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"Salary\":25000.0},{\"FirstName\":\"Ayan\",\"LastName\":\"Banerjee\",\"Address\":\"Bangalore\",\"Email\":\"test1@test.com\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"Salary\":30000.0},{\"FirstName\":\"Palak\",\"LastName\":\"Thakur\",\"Address\":\"Bangalore\",\"Email\":\"test2@test.com\",\"Gender\":\"Female\",\"Salary\":22000.0}]"

Its in string format and i want it in JSON. where am i wrong? please suggest

Comment: It just needs to be `return Json(userList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

Comment: and in my View, do i need to make any changes?

Comment: You haven't shown anything in your view with regards to KendoUI Grid!

Comment: my question is just regarding json.. I am validating my JSON Output in JsonLint.com and its giving me errors..i just want my view to return pure Json

Comment: Which is what `return Json(userList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` will do. But you have not shown the javascirpt where you call `DisplayUserDetails()` (so the . If your referring to `@{ var json = ViewBag.Response; }` or `@foreach (var item in json) {..` then you completely on the wrong track.